# BeautifulSoup does incorrectly filter out text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to filter out HTML tags from a text e-mail. Unfortunately I'm facing an issue for a particular e-mail that contains a `<` sign. I'm expecting BeautifulSoup to ignore the "tag" but it filters out everything after the `<` sign. I tried with all the parsers.

*Edit*: Actually I found out that html.parser (the default parser) does the job. I just couldn't spot my typo at first. But why are the other parsers having this issue?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = r"""Hallo,
&nbsp;
------------------&nbsp;Original&nbsp;------------------
From: &nbsp;"foo"<foo@example.com&gt;;
Subject: &nbsp;New message

Expected
"""
for parser in ('html5lib', 'html.parser', 'lxml'):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)
    text = soup.get_text()
    print(parser)
    print(text)
    print("Expected" in text)
```

The output is as follows:

```
html5lib
Hallo,
 
------------------ Original ------------------
From:  "foo"
False
html.parser
Hallo,
 
------------------ Original ------------------
From:  "foo"<foo@example.com>;
Subject:  New message

Expected

True
lxml
Hallo,
 
------------------ Original ------------------
From:  "foo"
False
```

*Edited*: I'm expecting the output to be something like

```
Hallo,
 
------------------ Original ------------------
From:  "foo"<foo@example.com>;
Subject:  New message

Expected
```

Comment: Not that it would matter for the result as it's False anyways, but you have a typo in "Excpected"

Comment: I think the issue is the email is not valid html but not valid escaped html either, so it can't be properly parsed by html5lib.  If you wanted to achieve an escaped < sign it would be &lt;

Comment: Also, did you mean to ignore the `parser` variable in your for loop? I think you probably intended `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)` -- if you make this change, you should find the html.parser parser does indeed handle for the bad encoding and print `True`

Comment: Thanks @lemonhead for pointing out the two typos. Fixed that. Now I identified that html.parser actually gives me the correct result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse a string that is only partially html-escaped; many parsers will not handle for this gracefully because it simply doesn't parse as you expect in the "language" the parser describes.
The `<` should actually be escaped as `&lt;` or else the entire rest of the email should be unescaped (and then properly escaped, e.g. with [`html.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape) before passing to parser)

That being said, it looks like the `html.parser` parser does properly handle for this, e.g. if you fix the hardcoded parser and typo in your code above:

```
for parser in ('html5lib', 'html.parser', 'lxml'):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)
    text = soup.get_text()
    print(parser)
    print(text)
    print("Expected" in text)
```

Outputs:

```
------------------ Original ------------------
From:  "foo"
False
html.parser
Hallo,
 
------------------ Original ------------------
From:  "foo"<foo@example.com>;
Subject:  New message

Expected

True
lxml
Hallo,
 
------------------ Original ------------------
From:  "foo"
False
```

Comment: Thank you @lemonhead, this is really a great answer. (I edited my question before I recognized your answer, only saw your comments)